# Why is $2n^3 > (n+1)^3$?

Tags: inequality

I am doing an induction proof and one of the intermediate steps is proving that $2n^3 > (n+1)^3$ when $n > 9$. Can someone show a short proof of why $2n^3 > (n+1)^3$ when $n>9$? I cannot see it.

Thank you

Comment: When $n=1,2,3$, this is not true. But this is true for larger $n$, since $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{2n^3}{(n+1)^3}=2$.

Comment: It is true when $n > 9$. I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$2n^3 > (n+1)^3 \iff n^3 > 3n^2 + 3n + 1$. Assume that $n \ge 7\implies n^3 \ge 7n^2 = 3n^2 + 3n^2 + n^2 \ge 3n^2 + 3n + 1$. Thus you're done.

Comment: Where was the intuition for the number $7$? How did you know that $7$ was the tipping point?

Comment: If you add the coefficients of the quadratic polynomial $3x^2+3x+1$ you get $3+3+1 =$ ?

Comment: That is fantastic! Is there any name to call such a process? Any context I can read that consists of adding coefficients of the polynomial?

Comment: I don't think there is any name for this process,and this kind of trick works for this particular problem only. For other questions, you might have to combine results, use related inequalities to prove the main statement.

Answer (score 4):

$$
2n^3>(n+1)^3\Longleftrightarrow\left(\frac{2^{1/3}n}{n+1}\right)^3>1\Longleftrightarrow\frac{2^{1/3}n}{n+1}>1\Longleftrightarrow n>\frac{1}{2^{1/3}-1}\approx 3.847.
$$

Comment: Nice. Easy to generalize, too.

Answer (score 1):

Note that :$(2^{1/3}-1)n=0.2599....>1$ when $n>3$ 
so $$n+1<n+(2^{1/3}-1)n= 2^{1/3}n\\ when\ n>3$$
We inequality by raising the third power.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, one that takes a little calculation but that also works: $2n^3\gt (n+1)^3$ iff $\dfrac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}\lt 2$ iff $\dfrac{(n+1)}{n}\lt\sqrt[3]{2}$ iff $1+\frac1n\lt\sqrt[3]{2}$ iff $\frac1n\lt\sqrt[3]{2}-1$ iff $n\gt\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}-1}$.  Now it's just calculation; you can show that $\sqrt[3]{2}\gt \frac54$ (since $2=\frac{128}{64}\gt\frac{5^3}{4^3}=\frac{125}{64}$), so the equation holds for all $n\gt 4$.

Answer (score 1):

$2n^3 > (n+1)^3 \iff n^3 > 3n^2 + 3n + 1$. None of the inequalities holds for $n\leq 3$.

But for $n\geq5$,

$n^3=n \times n^2> 4 \times n^2= 3n^2+n^2>3n^2+3n+1$ (Because, $n^2>3n+1$ for $n>3$).

So, $2n^3 > (n+1)^3$ holds for $n\geq 5$.

Moreover, it can be verify that it holds for $n=4$.

Hence, $2n^3 > (n+1)^3$ holds for $n\geq 4$.